# MySQL formatting query - Setting column Results as a Table header

Tags: mysql, formatting

I am trying to create a report in MySQL to output number of Traded Shares, by Client and by Market.

I have got the results I want (using multiple tables), but need to change the output table so that the results from one column become the header of another, and then have the quantity for Client by Market.

This is what I have so far;

```
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(sc.name,"All Clients") as "Clients",
 IFNULL(o.exchangeid,"All Markets") as "Markets",  
SUM(o.filledqty) as "Total Shares"
from ixrisk.orders o, ixrisk.clients c, ixrisk.sub_clients sc
where c.sub_client_id = sc.id and o.compid = c.clientname
GROUP BY sc.name, o.exchangeid WITH ROLLUP;
+------------------+-------------+--------------+
| Clients          | Markets     | Total Shares |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+
| FIXN_CL_CLIENT_1 | AMS         |           70 |
| FIXN_CL_CLIENT_1 | BTE         |          112 |
| FIXN_CL_CLIENT_1 | LSE         |         1147 |
| FIXN_CL_CLIENT_1 | All Markets |         1329 |
| qa_client_tst1   | LSE         |            0 |
| qa_client_tst1   | All Markets |            0 |
| All Clients      | All Markets |         1329 |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I would like it to come out like this, but cannot get it to.

```
+------------------+------+------+------+-------------+
| Clients          | AMS  | BTE  | LSE  | All Markets |
+------------------+------+------+------+-------------+
| FIXN_CL_CLIENT_1 | 70   | 112  | 1147 |  1329       |
| qa_client_tst1   | 0    | 0    | 0    |  0          |
| All Clients      | 70   | 112  | 1147 |  1329       |
+------------------+------+------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have looked through the similar subjects, and tried 'inner joins' and 'pivots', but couldn't get them work with my other parameters.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

**UPDATE**
I have amended the MySQL script to get the format I want now, but need to have each Client with just one line with all Exchange values.
I have tried various combinations and can get a single row, but the values do not populate correctly.

Comment: For better understanding can you make same sample entries and make a js fiddle?

Comment: That's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. The workarounds get extremely ugly, extremely quickly.

Comment: If you are not looking for response and other solution answer yourself, If still looking forward better solution notify intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    mysql> select sc.name,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'AMS' then o.filledqty end),0) as AMS,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'BRU' then o.filledqty end),0) as BRU,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'BTE' then o.filledqty end),0) as BTE,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'CHI' then o.filledqty end),0) as CHI,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'CPH' then o.filledqty end),0) as CPH,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'GER' then o.filledqty end),0) as GER,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'HEX' then o.filledqty end),0) as HEX,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'JNB' then o.filledqty end),0) as JNB,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'LIS' then o.filledqty end),0) as LIS,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'LSE' then o.filledqty end),0) as LSE,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'MCE' then o.filledqty end),0) as MCE,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'MIL' then o.filledqty end),0) as MIL,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'OSL' then o.filledqty end),0) as OSL,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'PAR' then o.filledqty end),0) as PAR,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'STO' then o.filledqty end),0) as STO,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'SWX' then o.filledqty end),0) as SWX,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'TRQ' then o.filledqty end),0) as TRQ,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'VIE' then o.filledqty end),0) as VIE,
COALESCE(SUM(case when `exchangeid` = 'VTX' then o.filledqty end),0) as VTX,
COALESCE(SUM(o.filledqty),0) as "All Markets"
from orders o
INNER JOIN clients c on o.compid = c.clientname
INNER JOIN sub_clients sc on c.sub_client_id = sc.id
INNER JOIN sub_clients sc on c.sub_client_id = sc.id
group by sc.name;
```